# What kind of rhetorical device is 'splaining?

Tags: argumentation, rhetoric

It is quite common for people to respond to an issue or question with the first thing that comes to mind, framed as a convincing explanation. When it appears to be a self-serving or unwarranted reasoning, it is sometimes called **'splaining**.

It used to be called "talking through your hat" or perhaps "sophistry". Is there a better name for it?

Comment: It is because people are uncomfortable with unanswered questions, and want to relieve people's stress.

Comment: Not sure there would be a name for it since, as you say, it's self-serving and doesn't really aim to persuade. Would there be a space for it in rhetoric, the art of persuasion?

Then again, maybe mansplaining is just called 'bad rhetoric'! Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: ["Mansplaining"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansplaining) is **NOT** merely offering the first explanation that comes to mind, and it's certainly not typically in response to a question. Rather, it's when, with little to no prompt of any kind, you condescendingly explain something that's potentially really simple, with little concern for whether the other person wants or already knows the explanation. And it especially applies when you explain something to someone who'd likely know more about the issue than you do (e.g. a non-biologist man explaining women's bodies to a woman).

Comment: @NotThatGuy ok. I guess I don't know more about it than you do, but the rest is correct :-)